# How to compare date from DB and JSON

Tags: jmeter

From **Database** I am getting Date value as "2011-03-31 00:00:00.0" 
From **JSON** response I am getting value as "2011-03-31"

How can I trim "00:00:00" from Database result and compare it with JSON response in JMeter using JSR223 assertion.

Comment: Show what you tried

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "trimming" is good option, I would rather go for "[parsing](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date)"

Here is an example of converting 2 dates in different formats to [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and comparing them

The code is supposed to be used in the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

```
def valueFromDB = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S', vars.get('valueFromDB'))
def valueFromJSON = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', vars.get('valueFromJSON'))

if (!valueFromDB.equals(valueFromJSON)) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Dates mismatch')
}
```

Replace `valueFromDB` and `valueFromJSON` with your own [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) names holding these values from the database and from JSON.

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)